# Handling aysnc data in a page NetxJS file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a webpage that pulls launch data from the SpaceX graphQL API, and then renders that data as a list. Users can click on a specific launch in that list that takes them to a 'details' page about that particular launch. 
On the details page, I'm trying to extract a paramter from the URL using `useRouter`. Upon logging out this paramter value to the browser, I've found that it's initially logged as `undefined`, and then shortly after the correct data is logged - I'm asusming this is some sort of async issue. 
I need the paramater for another API call, however I can't do that if it's not loading instantly - I've tried putting it into an `async/await` function but it hasn;t helped. Suggestion?

Details page: ***[paramter].js***

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useContext,useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { LaunchContext } from '../spacexContext'

const Items =   () => {
    const data =  useContext(LaunchContext)
    const router = useRouter()
    console.log(router.query.paramter)
    
        const getLaunchData = async () => {
            const [ launchData,setLaunchData ] = useState([])
            let parameters = await router.query.parameter
            setLaunchData(parameters)
            return launchData
        }

       const parameter =  getLaunchData()


    return ( 
        <div>
            this is items
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Items;
```

Included a screen shot of the console in the browser when I redirect to `/launchesPast` route

[image: Errors in the console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by how [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats) works:

> Pages that are statically optimized by Automatic Static Optimization
> will be hydrated without their route parameters provided, i.e query
> will be an empty object ({}).
>
> After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to
> provide the route parameters in the query object.

You can return null when the parameter is undefined, or you can try some solutions shared in this issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11484